# Group by Day of Month

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table `logins` with just the `bigint id` ,a `date_login` of type `datetime`, and `fk_user` of type `bigint`. I need to select the first and last logins for each day of the month in the specified year.

I was guessing something like:

```
select *theDayOfTheMonth*,min(date_login), max(date_login)
from logins
where year(date_login) = *theYearInput* and
and fk_user = *theKeySpecified* and
month(date_login) = *theMonthInput*
group by *theDayOfTheMonth*
```

but I don't know how to group by that day of month. How can I do this?

Comment: You will need to group by the user id too.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I _suspect_ that's true, but it's not actually part of the problem statement. It's possible they also want to know which users was first and last each day. Also, it looks like the WHERE clause will take care of this, such that only records for a specific user are considered anyway.

Comment: are you sure? I only want to know these operations for one user at a time not all of them @Nathan_Sav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. It will look something like this:

```
SELECT DATE(date_login) as dayOfMonth, min(date_login), max(date_login)
FROM logins
WHERE year(date_login) = @theYearInput
    and fk_user = @theKeySpecified
    and month(date_login) = @theMonthInput
GROUP BY DATE(date_login)
```

Alternatively you might use [the `Day()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day) instead, which should still work because the query is limited to a single specific month via conditions in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT DAY(date_login) as dayOfMonth, min(date_login), max(date_login)
FROM logins
WHERE year(date_login) = @theYearInput
    and fk_user = @theKeySpecified
    and month(date_login) = @theMonthInput
GROUP BY DAY(date_login)
```

Functionally, given these conditions the only difference between them is the format of the first column in the output. However, if you later need to expand across larger date ranges the first version will handle that better.

Answer (score 0):

The function that you are looking for is `DayOfMonth()`

> ```
> create table logins(
> fk_user bigint,
> date_login datetime);
> insert into logins values
> (1,'2022-01-01 09:00:00'),(1,'2022-01-01 18:00:00'),(1,'2022-01-02 08:00:00'),(1,'2022-01-02 16:00:00')
> ```

> ```
> select 
>   DayOfMonth(date_login) day,
>   min(date_login) first_login, 
>   max(date_login) last_login
> from logins
> where year(date_login) = 2022 
> and fk_user = 1 and
> month(date_login) = 1
> group by DayOfMonth(date_login);
> ```
>
> ```
> day | first_login         | last_login         
> --: | :------------------ | :------------------
>   1 | 2022-01-01 09:00:00 | 2022-01-01 18:00:00
>   2 | 2022-01-02 08:00:00 | 2022-01-02 16:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=636c04d39a845ba681b8f898d6e3304d)*